Count parameter not working in pybliometrics
Using pybliometrics with the count parameter:
import pybliometrics
pybliometrics.scopus.init()
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

s = ScopusSearch('artificial AND intelligence AND genetics AND research AND healthcare', count=10, view="COMPLETE")

The expected behavior would be to limit the results to only 10, however it is not doing that.

The count parameter doesn't work as expected for the Scopus Search API. The number of results equals the count parameter times the number of result pages. Unlike the other search API, Scopus Search API uses pagination to cycle through the results set. When you provide count, the API returns this number for each page rather than in total.
Also, it only applies when pybliometrics downloads something. Cached results will take precedence otherwise.

Thank you for the quick response. Is there some way to download the complete view while limiting the results downloaded with some parameter in pybliometrics?

What do you mean? You want just some information from the COMPLETE view?

Yes, my objective is to use the count parameter of the scopus api (https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/ScopusSearchAPI.wadl) together with the COMPLETE view, to download abstract, citation count, title and doi from up to 5000 articles.

pybliometrics cycles through the results pages itself, so you don't need to fiddle with the count parameter. For the rest I suggest to simply download everything and just use the columns you need. Much easier.

My objective is to limit the download quantity. I can do that after downloading everything; however, that would mean that in some cases I would download 1,000,000 results to get only the 5,000 with the most citations, which I would utilize for my research. So it would be optimal if I could use a parameter, like the count parameter, to limit the total quantity of results downloaded, as it is described in the Scopus API.

The documentation is not that reliable, unfortunately. It was written before they introduced pagination for the Scopus Search API. If you compare the documentation for the count parameter for that of the Affiliation Search API, which does not support pagination, you will see that the text is the same - which it shouldn't.
